# How to reset kali linux password in windows subsystem for linux

Tags: kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, password-recovery

I have installed Kali Linux subsystem on windows. And now I have forgotten the root password in Kali, there is just the terminal of Kali Linux and nothing else. How can I reset my password safely?

Note: I have installed both Ubuntu and Kali Linux installed at the same time
But when I run bash by default it opens up ubuntu

Comment: Can you open the wsl.exe? Did you see any prompt?

Comment: yes its open in path /mnt/c/Users/Noman^Alien#0637

Comment: The problem is I have forgotten my current password and can't get access to the root

Comment: Open the `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss` registry. Find the registry value `DistributionName==Kali_Linux`. Change defaultUID registry to zero. Open Kali, type `passwd` change root password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have installed both Ubuntu and Kali Linux installed at the same time But when I run bash by default it opens up Ubuntu.

In new Windows versions, users can install and run multiple GNU/Linux distributions. One can configure the default distribution (i.e. the distribution that comes up with `wsl.exe`) with `wslconfig /s <disrto_name>` command. e.g. To open Kali with `wsl.exe` at first run, use this command `wslconfig /s kali-linux` or run `kali.exe`.

> I have forgotten the root password in Kali, there is just the terminal of Kali Linux and nothing else. How can I reset my password safely?

First of all, I don't know if this procedure is safe or not. At the time of writing, WSL manages the default login user from `DefaultUID` registry (this may change in future). Close any opened WSL instance. To edit this registry value, open Registry Editor or `regedit.exe` from start menu or run dialog box. Go to this registry path or type this path with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in that Window:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss
```

You may see one or multiple subkeys (like subfolders) with names something like `{12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012}` (called GUID). Double click on them to open one-by-one and match the `DistributionName` value with your desired distribution name, here it will be `kali-linux` (see below). Double click on the `DefaultUID` value and change it to ZERO. Zero is for root user and `1000` or `0x3e8` (in hexadecimal) for normal users.

Open `wsl.exe` in command prompt. The prompt changes from `$` to `#` (means root user). Run `passwd` command in Kali, change root password as usual. Now go back to previous registry key, change Zero to previous value (or `3e8` in hex). Here is an example of the registry values:

```vbs
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss]
"DefaultDistribution"="{f029d4cd-b7ee-42bc-ae02-af8f2c97f495}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\{f029d4cd-b7ee-42bc-ae02-af8f2c97f495}]
"State"=dword:00000001
"DistributionName"="kali-linux"
"Version"=dword:00000001
"BasePath"="C:\\MyFiles\\kali-linux"
"KernelCommandLine"="BOOT_IMAGE=/kernel init=/init ro"
"DefaultUid"=dword:000003e8
"Flags"=dword:00000007
```

### Further details:

- [Managing multiple Linux Distributions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#managing-multiple-linux-distributions)
- [`passwd` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html)
- [How to reset Kali linux root password](https://superuser.com/a/1009555/726810)

Comment: Editing the registry is not the appropriate way to temporarily change the default user to root. Please see the answer by @mike-v, which is the official Microsoft recommendation and which should also be promoted to being the right answer.

Answer (score 10):

I appreciate this is an older question but I wanted to provide the answer based on Microsoft guidance as I stumbled across this and knew there had to be a better way.

This is based on the article available at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/user-support running the device running at least Windows 10 1709 (Fall Creators Update)

1. Ensure Kali is not running
2. Open a command prompt (`cmd.exe`)
3. From the command prompt, run `kali config --default-user root`
4. Run Kali, you should login as root automatically
5. In Kali, run `passwd user` where user is the username of the account you wish the reset the password for, i.e. `passwd bob`
6. Follow the prompts to reset the password and then type `exit` to close Kali
7. From the command prompt, run `kali config --default-user user` where user is the username you have just reset the password for, i.e. `kali config --default-user bob`

Following these steps, you should be able to reset the password for your account in Kali on WSL.

Comment: Should be promoted to "accepted answer".

Comment: @RichardOnslowRoper - Impossible. Only the author can accept an answer

Comment: This worked with Ubuntu as the WSL image as well. Instead of `kali`, I substituted `ubuntu` and it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is given by [biswapriyo](https://superuser.com/users/726810/biswapriyo). Thanks to him

Open the run command in windows by pressing `Win + R`
Type `wsl.exe`
Or open the bash window from the windows start menu
If you got a bash window running then follow the steps below

**If you have forgotten the user name**

Type `cat /etc/passwd`
There you can see the username there

***Retrieving the password***

Open the run command again and type `regedit`

Go to

> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss

registry.

Find the registry value `DistributionName==Kali_Linux.`

*Export the current registry in case something goes wrong and you can go back*

Change `defaultUID` **registry to zero**. *[But remember the old value too]*

Open Kali, type `passwd` change root password.

> Next time to avoid the root login in kali change the defaultUID registry to the old value