# How to sign in as "root" in bash on Windows by Windows Subsystem For Linux

Tags: linux, bash, root, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried using the command -`lxrun /setdefaultuser root`
but I get a error :

```
  Warning: lxrun.exe is only used to configure the legacy Windows Subsystem for Linux distribution.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore

    The Windows Subsystem for Linux has an install or uninstall operation pending.
```

Although I have turned on the Windows Subsystems For Linux.

Comment: It's already telling you what you need to do. Did you install a distribution and did you check whenever an install is pending? Did you reboot after installing the feature?

Comment: Upgrade Windows as soon as possible. LxRun is obsolete. Use distro from Windows Store.

Comment: Kind of similar: http://superuser.com/questions/1330054/

Comment: @Seth It has been months since I have installed Ubuntu for Windows from Windows Store, so rebooting is not an issue I guess. And I can't get what install is supposed to be pending after installation of distro. from the store?