# How to reset my WSL Ubuntu password?

Tags: ubuntu, wsl2, password-recovery

I forgot my WSL Ubuntu password, needed to run **sudo** command.
After running the folowing command

`lead@kernel:~$ sudo su`

I got this

`Sorry, try again`

Any alternatives? Thanks

Comment: Run *wsl -u root* and use passwd to change the password for user lead

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1330054/how-to-reset-kali-linux-password-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux/1330118#1330118) has the answer to your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset kali linux password in windows subsystem for linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1330054/how-to-reset-kali-linux-password-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux)

Comment: The procedure as outlined in the answer https://superuser.com/a/1369917/310704 worked worked fine for me. I just had to substitute `ubuntu` for `kali` since I'm using Ubuntu with WSL. Thanks @MarkusMeyer.